# ckeditor: adding span inside div tag

Tags: ckeditor, html

I am trying to add span inside the div tag but the code I have tried so far just creates a `div` or a `span` element at a time.
Here is code I am trying:

```
style : new CKEDITOR.style( {
    // element :'div',
    // attributes : { 'itemscope' : '' },
    element : 'span',
    attributes : { 'itemscope' : '', 'itemprop' : parts[ 1 ], 'name' :  parts[0] },
} ),

onClick : function() {
    this.style.apply( editor.document );
}
```